# Xcode: How to make a grid of 3x3 images take up 1/3 of the width and height?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to make a view with 9 buttons, all that have 1/3 of the screen height and 1/3 of the screen width. I'm using storyboards. This is what I have now:

[image]

As you can see, they aren't in the right positions. Is there an easy way to get all the buttons to have the proper dimensions?

Comment: are you using Autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@medvedNick has the right idea, but if you're targeting iOS 9 or later, you can save yourself from managing quite so many Auto Layout constraints by using [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/index.html).

Just make one vertical stack view containing three horizontal stack views (or vice versa), each of which has three buttons, and set all the stack view's distribution to Fill Equally. You'll still need a couple sets of  constraints — one to make the outer stack view fill the screen, and one to make the inner horizontal stack views fill the width of the outer vertical stack view.

At run time, this gets you roughly the same effect as setting your own layout constraints (because `UIStackView` creates constraints to manage its subviews)... but it makes the constraint setup simpler for you at design time. For example, if you want this whole grid of buttons to fill only half the screen, you can just change the constraint that sets the width (or height) of the outer stack view.

(This example doesn't leverage all that `UIStackView` can do, by the way. If your views aren't all supposed to be lined up in a grid, if they change size, or if you add/remove views at runtime, `UIStackView` can be even more help.)

Comment: Thanks I ended up using collection view since I'm supporting iOS 8 but good to know about stack view!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need is to set correct constraints for all buttons.

These are:

1. Leading constrains with constant 0 for all buttons
2. Top constraints with constant 0 for all buttons
3. Trailing constrains with constant 0 for all buttons
4. Bottom constraints with constant 0 for all buttons
5. Equal width constraints for all buttons
6. Equal height constraints for all buttons

How to:

1. Select all buttons
2. Add leading, top, width and height constraints

[image: like this]

3. Select left-row and bottom buttons
4. Add right and bottom constraints as in step 2

Make sure you turn off `Constrain to margins` when adding constraints of 1-4